# Realizar dos split

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

estoy haciendo un split en donde primero borro una parte de mi url, a esto le asigno una variable, luego a esta solo necesito que queden desde el :4200 en adelante se borre, yo pensaba realizar 2 split, pero no me resulta, adjunto una imagen de lo que quiero cortar y el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 
  let url = window.location.href
  let officeUrl = url.split("http://")
  console.log(officeUrl[1])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar [new URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) para obtener información de una url sin la necesidad de usar split

```js
const url = new URL( "https://192.168.0.2:4200/dahsboard_Sistma");

console.log(url.hostname);
console.log(url.href);
console.log(url.origin);
console.log(url.pathname);
console.log(url.port);
console.log(url.protocol);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar split para cortar la cadena de esta manera:

```
let url : string = '192.168.1.1:4200/dashboard_Sistema';
let modifiedUrl : string = ':4200' + url.split(':4200')[1];
console.log(modifiedUrl);
```

o bien usando una expresion regular:

```
modifiedUrl.match(/:4200.+/gm).toString()
console.log(modifiedUrl)
```